# Import and read the contents of a CSS file as text (React/webpack)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

What I'm trying to do is import the css file, read its contents, and then create an array of class names.

However, the following produces a log of empty object.

```
import TextCSS from './textfield.css'
console.log(TextCSS)
```

I've been searching the NPM for a package that could do that, Github and Google, tried a few packages with promising names, but so far nothing.

Comment: did you try fsread? https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_filesystem.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [this configuration](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#tostring)

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

it looks like you should also be able to import the css file and then call to string on it if you've got the 'css-loader' plugin setup

```
const css = require('./test.css').toString();
```

Answer (score 5):

## **create-react-app solution 2023**

### Code:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-webpack-loader-syntax
import css from '!!css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"exportType":"string"}!./styles.css';
```

### Explanation:

CRA uses Webpack under the hood, but does not allow editing webpack.config.js.
Many solutions for this question recommend installing raw-loader which is [deprecated](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader) as of 2021. The recommended migration solution is called asset modules, which requires editing the webpack.config.js file (again, we don't have access to it in CRA).

So the completely vanilla solution, without installing third-party packages that are not native to CRA, is to use [inline loaders](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#inline).

1. Find the [loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/) we need. In this example, it is [css-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/). There are other options for different file types.
2. Check the loader [options](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#options) to see if we can get the format we need, in this case a string. We confirm that there is a [string option](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#exporttype) for our loader.
3. Write the code with our desired options. Starting with a basic import:

   ```
    import css from './styles.css'
   ```

   we specify our desired loader:

   ```
    import css from '!!css-loader!./styles.css'
   ```

   and then pass our options in as a JSON object query parameter:

   ```
    import css from '!!css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"exportType":"string"}!./styles.css'
   ```

   I set sourceMap option to false because if otherwise unspecified, the imported string contains a comment at the end containing compressed data about the file.

   Finally, command your linter to ignore the non-standard syntax:

   ```
    // eslint-disable-next-line import/no-webpack-loader-syntax
    import css from '!!css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"exportType":"string"}!./styles.css';
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You can load the css file as module in React, but it has to me named with `mystyle.module.css` nut just `mystyle.css`. Then you can do

```
import styles from './mystyles.module.css'
console.log(styles)
```

More on React CSS modules: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet
More on CSS modules: https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-1-need/

Answer (score 0):

If you use webpack, try to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-to-string-loader loader

```
var styleString = require('css-to-string-loader!css-loader!./file.css');
```

Comment: Getting this: Unexpected '!' in 'css-to-string-loader!css-loader!./textfield.css'. Do not use import syntax to configure webpack loaders  import/no-webpack-loader-syntax